# TinkerPop Gremlin with Spring data

Tags: spring, spring-data, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a use-case for graph based DB in my project and I was wondering if there is an API for Gremlin TinkerPop with Spring Data like there is for Relational and NoSql like JPA and MongoDB. I'm aware of the community support for Microsoft's Azure Cosmos DB (Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB) but I'm planning to use Neptune on AWS. In case Spring Data isn't an option, is there any other Java library that will give predefined data access methods and reduce the boiler plate code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will find one that could work with Neptune. Neptune does so many things differently than other graph databases. I consider Microsoft version of Spring data for Cosmos DB very basic and naive.
We are in the process of building our own Spring Data for Neptune for our upcoming projects.
I would recommend the same for you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This library is not specifically for Spring, but if your real need is to remove the amount of boiler plate code, it should help a lot. It is a topology aware client that can help with areas that include:

1. Connection management
2. Cluster topology changes (e.g. failover -> IP address changes)
3. SigV4 signing for IAM enabled clusters

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/neptune-gremlin-client